# Unable to order the functions call returns from the background script

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, event-loop, browser-extension

I am working on a browser extension, most browser extension make use of the content script & the background script.

I am implementing a feature that involves the user inputting a link and some text in a text area and I am extracting the URL and showing an UrlPreviewToast React component that consists of the og-image, og-title & og-description.

The toast only appears when the user enters a valid link, this all happens in real-time (as the user typing)

If the user enters multiple links, I plan only to show the preview for the first link.

```js
useEffect(() => {

            const url = value.match(/(https?:\/\/[^\s]+)/g)?.[0];
            if (!url) return setUserLinkExtract(null);

            (async () => {
                const dom = await extractDomFromBackground(url); // stringified dom
                if (!dom) return setUserLinkExtract(null);

                const parser = new DOMParser();
                const htmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(dom, "text/html");

                const ogTitle = /* extract title*/
                const ogDescription = /* extract description*/
                const ogImage = /* extract image*/

                setUserLinkExtract({
                    dom: dom,
                    ogTags: {
                        description: ogDescription,
                        image: ogImage,
                        title: ogTitle,
                    },
                    title: ogTitle,
                    url: url,
                });
            })();
        }, [deferredValue]);
```

Background script:

```js
export async function extractDomFromBackground(url: string): Promise<string> {
    try {
        const options = {
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "text/html",
                "User-Agent": `Chrome/90.0.4430.212`,
            },
            method: "GET",
        };

        const res = await fetch(url, options);
        if (!res.ok && res.status !== 200) return "";

        const dom = await res.text();
        return dom;
    } catch (e) {
        return "";
    }
}
```

so here is the problem I am facing, when a user enter a invalid url let's say `https://www.google.co` and then types `https://www.google.com` the response for `https://www.google.co` is recived later in my react hook, after `https://www.google.com` so the final value of `setUserLinkExtract` is set to null ( dom obtained from https://www.google.co) when It should be the dom of https://www.google.com. so in the end the toast does not show up because the value of `setUserLinkExtract` is null.

PS: I prefer not to add any third party packages as that would increase the bundle size of my already large extension. so sadly no fancy stuff like cheerio :(

Thanks guys

I tried using abortController, but many a times, my request to obtain the dom for a valid url was aborted by the controller.